# On change of drop-down update the form in alfresco workflow

Tags: javascript, forms, share, alfresco

I need help on the alfresco workflow form.

Scenario: i have one dropdown, with values as High, Medium, Low

If dropdown value change to **medium**, i need **value 2** in message box.

If dropdown value change to **High**, i need **value 1** in message box.

Even javascript will help.

[image: workflow form]

**share-config-custom.xml**

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$qwfActivitiAdhoc">

   <forms>
         <form>

            <field-visibility>  <show id="Priority" />  </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                  <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.general" />
                  <field id="Priority"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl" /></field>   

            </appearance>

         </form>

      </forms>

      <forms>
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
               <show id="bpm:workflowDescription" />

            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
               <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.general" />
               <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label-id="workflow.field.message">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                     <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
                  </control>
               </field>

            </appearance>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Follow below things..

1. Create new ftl in *"/com/companyName/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl"* location
2. Give above path in share-config-custom.xml
3. In new priority.ftl,you have to create new object of javascrit yui module, like we are doing it in dashlet.
4. In that module get message textarea using javascript and set value.

For more information ,check the implementation of richtext.ftl in alfresco share.

Comment: Thank you , i am from other domain, so it will be nice, if you please elaborate bit and share sample code. i really appreciate your help.